# How to check a Lie algebra homomorphism

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra and $A$ be its subalgebra. Let consider $h : A \to Der(L)$ defined by $h(a)(l)=[l,a]$ then how to show that $h$ is Lie algebra homomorphism?

According to the definition of Lie algebras homomorphisms $h$ must satisfies 
$ h([a_1,a_2])=[h(a_1),h(a_2)]$. Using Jacobi identity, we need to prove that $[[l_1,l_2]a]$  equals to $[[l_1,a],[l_2,a]]$ ? I have problem with calculation of Jacobi identity!

Edit: There are useful answers to this question:
Checking a Lie homomorphism has been described carefully in [Adjoint map is Lie homomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339289/adjoint-map-is-lie-homomorphism) and [Adjoint map is a Lie homomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2484188/adjoint-map-is-a-lie-homomorphism?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Many Thanks. Is it true to follow this way to show Leibniz homomorphisms?

Comment: For right Leibniz algebra $L$, the right multiplication is a derivation, so  if we define $h: L \to Der(L)$ then how to prove it is Leibniz homomorphism?

Comment: I found my old proof again, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2484188/adjoint-map-is-a-lie-homomorphism). For Leibniz you have to rewrite Jacobi either to "left Leibniz", or "right Leibniz".

Comment: Your old proof is clear and useful. In the case of Leibniz algebras, if we write $h: A \to Der(L)$ where $A$ is a subalgebra of $L$, then still it works? Means is it Leibniz homomorphism?

Comment: Yes, the adjoint map is a Leibniz algebra representation.